# "Datatime" datatype is getting changed in ResultSet as VARCHAR when I use GROUP BY with ORDER BY (MYSQL 5.6)

Tags: mysql

Recently I have upgraded mysql version 5.5 to 5.6.
Column name:Time and data type is "datetime".
The below query giving output as "`varchar`" type instead of `datetime` type. 
**Same query returns with `datetime` type in my old mysql database(version 5.5)**

```
( SELECT Time 
  FROM <table> 
  WHERE id=1 
    and Time>= '1969-12-31 19:00:00.0'  
  GROUP BY Time 
  ORDER BY Time )  
ORDER BY Time LIMIT  0, 1
```

I have used below query to get data type of Time column

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp1`
( SELECT Time 
  FROM <table> 
  WHERE id=1 
    and Time>= '1969-12-31 19:00:00.0'  
    and trId=1 
  GROUP BY Time 
  ORDER BY Time )  
ORDER BY Time LIMIT  0, 1

describe temp1
```

Is there any config change needed in 5.6 version. If I remove GROUP BY or ORDER BY(second ORDER BY) it works fine. I am not sure why its behaves differently.

Comment: How do you determine the returned column type?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I have used below query to get datatype.CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp1`
( SELECT Time 
  FROM <table> 
  WHERE id=1 
    and Time>= '1969-12-31 19:00:00.0'  
    and trId=1 
  GROUP BY Time 
  ORDER BY Time )  
ORDER BY Time LIMIT  0, 1

describe temp1

Comment: That information should be included in your question. Please also post the CREATE statement for your original table and some sample data (INSERT statements).

Comment: Please also post output of `SELECT @@version`. Because this is not reproduceable in 8.0.16

Comment: @Luuk Versions are posted in the question: 5.5 => DATETIME; 5.6 => VARCHAR. I can reproduce that in a fiddle.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: I recall seeing a bug report about this behavior, but was not able to find it again. That's why I was interested in the 'x' in '5.6.x'.

Comment: @Luuk The "Bug" is still present in 5.7 but not in 8.0 ([fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fYdqLMJSMkj3LGCGnq48Pw/0))

Comment: Also interesting: If I remove one of the ORDER BY clauses, I get DATETIME in any version. Looks really like a bug in the optimizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess because SELECT is betweeen parenthesis a new temporary table is created, and field types are not declared.

Try SELECT CAST(Time AS datetime) AS Time

Comment: no, `EXPLAIN` shows no temporary table is created. The first `ORDER BY` seems to be ignored, together with the parenthesis. (But, indeed, it's an odd way to write an SQL statement)

Comment: But same query works fine in mysql 5.5 without any typecasting.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE test;

CREATE TABLE datumtijd (i integer PRIMARY KEY, d datetime);
INSERT INTO datumtijd VALUES (1,NOW());
INSERT INTO datumtijd VALUES (2,NOW());
INSERT INTO datumtijd VALUES (3,NOW());

create table test1 select * from datumtijd order by d;
create table test2 select * from datumtijd group by d order by d;
create table test3 select * from datumtijd group by d order by d limit 0,1;

show create table test3;

select @@version;
```

All 'test' tables (`test1`,`test2`,`test3`) are defined with the second column having a datatype datetime.

```
> show create table test3

+ ---------- + ----------------- +
| Table      | Create Table      |
+ ---------- + ----------------- +
| test3      | CREATE TABLE `test3` (
  `i` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `d` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+ ---------- + ----------------- +
1 rows
```